# Convert server file into HTML

Tags: shiny

Wanted to check if I can convert server.R file into HTML. Sample server file below

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$greeting <- renderText({
    paste0("Hello, ", input$name, "!")
  })
  print(getwd())
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, try `shinyAce`. See my example below. It not only gives you the nice html box around it and also r syntax highlight.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyAce)
# load your server file for the right path
server_text <- readLines("server.R")
ui <- fluidPage(
    aceEditor(outputId = "show_server", value = server_text, readOnly = TRUE, mode = "r")
)
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```